# Send Hex command with QByteArray and QFile

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qbytearray

so i need to send thru UART a command which is in Hex. 
I tried to assign directly to QByteArray but without success

```
QByteArray test = 0x21, 0x30, 0xFF... //the result is that test is empty.
```

I did try to assign thru a QString

`QString t = 0x21, 0x30, 0xFF...`

```
file->write(t.toLatin1()) //also without success.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QByteArray test = QByteArrayLiteral("\xDE\xAD\xBE\xEF");
```

That should work.

Also, you might want want to work on them C++ skills a bit more, because what you attempted is definitely not how the language works. A list initializer maybe... but comma separated values?